# jQuery not detecting dynamic html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of folders that are represented as links using a VueJS for-loop, wit data pulled from API. For each of those links, I am using a library called x-editable to allow for the editing of the names. Essentially, when you click on the link with defined attributes (assuming you instantiate via editable(), it will bring up a pop-over).

I find that if I create a dummy link (outside of the for loop) and include the instantiation in a document.ready block, it works just fine:

EDIT: Note that the ready: function() is a custom document.ready function, defined in a Vuejs router.

```
ready: function() {
    jQuery.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    jQuery('.editable').editable();
},
```

However, none of the dynamically generated links work when they are clicked. My guess is that jQuery is simply not detecting them, as they were not made when the document was loaded.

I tried to call editable after the data was received and assigned to Vue:

```
//Folders
this.$http.get('/api/folders').then(function(response) {
    this.state.folders = response.data;
    jQuery('.editable').editable();
});
```

However, it seems that this doesn't work either. I read that you can bind events using .on() which will work with generated elements. However, .editable() isn't really an event (I think). Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: for dynamically generate html, after the html is generated you need to call `jQuery('.editable').editable();`

Comment: Can you have a callback after new elements get added to the DOM, where you can call `editable()` on them?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I updated my post, but the ready function is called when the document is ready.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov edited post with what I tried to do along those lines

Comment: @mdobrenko - are you sure the new elements you add in the callback with `this.state.folders = response.data` have class `editable`? Because if they don't, nothing will happen to them.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov Yep -- the attributes are identical to those of the dummy generated version.

Comment: @mdobrenko - well, the only thing I can think of, is that VueJS (which I'm not familiar with) might be processing new data asynchronously too, so maybe you need to move `jQuery('.editable').editable()` to the VueJS callback.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov I added that statement to the VueJS callback, but unfortunately it looks like jQuery can't find them (I tried add an .each()) and it only detected the dummy instance.

Comment: @mdobrenko - I sometimes think that way too )), but the truth is jQuery will find everything as long as it is in the DOM. You have to figure out why it is not in the DOM when you run jQuery. Also can you add to your question an example of server response you get.